# How can I strike-out arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am using the following code to draw a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) using tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\small{\begin{tikzpicture}[%
 ->,
 shorten >=2pt,
 >=stealth,
 node distance=1cm,
 pil/.style={
 ->,
 thick,
 shorten =2pt,}
 ]
 \node (1) {A};
 \node[left=of 1] (2) {L};
 \node[right=of 1] (3) {Y};
 \draw [->] (2.east) -- (1.west);
 \draw [->] (1.east) -- (3.west);
 \draw [->] (2) to [out=15, in=165] (3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}
```

I would like to be able draw a slash or strike-out through the arrow from L to A (the first arrow in the code) to indicate that the analysis method removes this association completely.

[image]

How can I modify the code to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This is especially important with `tikz` as there are so many libraries that could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way which draws a diagonal line from the midpoint where the `x` and `y` is set via the macro `\StrikeThruDistance` as is shown by the red strike out.

You could also define a custom arrow as in the `strike thru arrow` style that I have defined below as shown by the blue arrow.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand*{\StrikeThruDistance}{0.15cm}%
\newcommand*{\StrikeThru}{\StrikeThruDistance,\StrikeThruDistance}%


\tikzset{strike thru arrow/.style={
    decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {
        \draw [blue, thick,-] 
            ++ (-\StrikeThruDistance,-\StrikeThruDistance) 
            -- ( \StrikeThruDistance, \StrikeThruDistance);}
    },
    postaction={decorate},
}}

\begin{document}


\small{\begin{tikzpicture}[%
 ->,
 shorten >=2pt,
 >=stealth,
 node distance=1cm,
 pil/.style={
     ->,
     thick,
     shorten =2pt,}
 ]
 \node (1) {A};
 \node[left=of 1] (2) {L};
 \node[right=of 1] (3) {Y};
 \draw [->] (2.east) -- (1.west);
    % Manually draw the strike thru
    \coordinate (MidWay) at ($(2.east)!0.5!(1.west)$);
    \draw [thick, red,-] ($(MidWay)-(\StrikeThru)$) -- 
            ($(MidWay)+(\StrikeThru)$);
 \draw [->, strike thru arrow] (1.east) -- (3.west);
 \draw [->] (2) to [out=15, in=165] (3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Manually it's possible to use another method :

1) I removed `->, shorten >=2pt` because I think it's preferable to define a new style like `pil`

2) I determined a new coordinate `m`placed at the middle of your arrow.

3) You can use the `($ ...$)` facility or use the old way with `shift`. I used the two possibilities in the next example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\small{\begin{tikzpicture}[%
 >=stealth,
 node distance = 1cm,
 pil/.style    = { ->,
                   thick,
                   shorten =2pt}]
 \node (1) {A};
 \node[left=of 1] (2) {L};
 \node[right=of 1] (3) {Y};
 \draw [->] (2.east) -- coordinate (m) (1.west);
 \draw[blue,shift={(m)}](-0.1,-0.1)--(0.1,+0.1);
 \draw [->] (1.east) -- coordinate (m)(3.west);
 \draw[red]($(m)+(-0.1,-0.1)$)--($(m)+(0.1,+0.1)$);
 \draw [->] (2) to [out=15, in=165] (3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This [(presumably a duplicate) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98202/how-to-draw-a-slash-into-the-line) offers an interesting alternative : just use a slash to typeset the strike-out.

The main advantage is the simplicity of the command, especially if the arrows are sloped and the strike-out need to be rotated accordingly. 
It comes at the expense of control over the look of the strike bar.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\small{\begin{tikzpicture}[%
 ->,
 shorten >=2pt,
 >=stealth,
 node distance=1cm,
 pil/.style={
 ->,
 thick,
 shorten =2pt,}
 ]
 \node (1) {A};
 \node[left=of 1] (2) {L};
 \node[right=of 1] (3) {Y};
 \draw [->] (2.east) -- (1.west) node[pos=0.5,red,sloped] {\tiny$/$};
 \draw [->] (1.east) -- (3.west) node[pos=0.5,blue,sloped] {\tiny$/$};
 \draw [->] (2) to [out=15, in=165] (3);
 \end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]