# How to draw a slash into the line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to add a slash into the line as described in the following picture.
[image]

Here is my code,however, I don't know how to add the slash, may someone help me?:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  my box/.style = {draw, minimum width = 2em, minimum height=1em},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]

\node[draw, diamond](condition){};
\node[my box,below= of condition](ru){};
\draw[->](condition)--(ru);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you might see [How can I strike-out arrows in tikz?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96967/13304) of which perhaps this is a duplicate.

Comment: I added to the linked question an answer directly relevant to the present question, typesetting a slash in the middle of the arrow.