# Striked arrows on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, tikz-arrows, graphs

I've been making this code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path     
      node (A) {$A$}
      (0:4cm)   node (B) {$B$}
      (-60:4cm) node (C) {$C$};
    \path[-stealth]
    (A) edge [bend right] node [left]  {}      (C)
    (C) edge              node [right] {} (A)
    (B) edge              node [right] {}      (C)
    (C) edge [bend right]             node [left] {}      (B)
    ([yshift=-2.5pt]A.east) edge node [above,yshift= 1.0ex]  {} ([yshift=-2.5pt]B.west)
    ([yshift= 2.5pt]B.west) edge node [below,yshift=-1.0ex]  {} ([yshift= 2.5pt]A.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

However, I need to have some strike-through arrows, for example from C to B, C to A, and A to B. How can I make them? Also, if it's possible, can I make a straight arrows there instead of the bended ones? Cheers!

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96967/how-can-i-strike-out-arrows-in-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the degree anchors of nodes in combination with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96967/how-can-i-strike-out-arrows-in-tikz) approach. Like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{every node/.style={circle}, 
         strike through/.append style={
    decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {
    \draw[-] ++ (-2pt,-2pt) -- (2pt,2pt);}
  },postaction={decorate}}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path       node (A) {$A$}
      (0:4cm)   node (B) {$B$}
      (-60:4cm) node (C) {$C$};
    \path[-stealth]
      (A.315) edge [strike through] (C.105)
      (C.135) edge                  (A.285)
      (B.255) edge                  (C.45)
      (C.75)  edge [strike through] (B.225) 
      (B.165) edge                  (A.15)
      (A.345) edge [strike through] (B.195);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Anyway, what's that 315, for example, mean? I mean, how do you count it?

Comment: Imagine the node to be a circle. 315 means the anchor is at 315 degrees counted counterclockwise from the east node (which is at 0 or at 360). So `(A.315) edge (C.105)` draws a line from the 315 degrees anchor of node A to the 105 degrees anchor of node C. The numbers are calculated as ±15 degrees from 0 and 300 degrees for node A, as ±15 degrees from 60 and 120 degrees for node C and as ±15 degrees from 180 and 240 degrees for node B.

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 34mm and 17mm
                        ]
    \node (A) {$A$};
    \node (C) [below right=of A]    {$C$};
    \node (B) [above right=of C]    {$C$};
    \path[-stealth]
    (A) edge [bend right]   (C)
    (C) edge    node[sloped] {$|$}  (A)
    (B) edge [bend  left]   (C)
    (C) edge    node[sloped]  {$|$} (B)
    ([yshift=-2.5pt] A.east)    edge ([yshift=-2.5pt] B.west)
    ([yshift= 2.5pt] B.west)    edge ([yshift= 2.5pt] A.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```