# Help to change the font size in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good afternoon,

I would like C=1 to appear on the same line within the node and all other nodes to be the same size.

I hope you can help me.

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{New}
\author{me }
\date{November 2021}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, fit, automata,  positioning, arrows}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle,text width=0.5cm,align=center}
]

\node[mynode] (z) {$Y$};
\node[mynode,right=of z] (x) {$\hat{Y}$};
\node[mynode,below=of z] (y) {$A$};
\node[mynode,below=of x] (w) {$C=1$};
\node[mynode,right=of w, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (e) {$U_C$};

\path (x) edge[latex-] (z);
\path (y) edge[-latex] (z);
\path (x) edge[latex-] (w);
\path (e) edge[-latex] (w);
\path (y) edge[-latex] (w);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Effect.}
\label{fig:effectcorrec}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Actual bad graph]

[image: how I want the graph]

Comment: Try adding `text depth=0.25ex` to the options of the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @user202729 done, sorry for any inconvenience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `$C=1$` to be smaller, you can use `\scalebox{0.8}{$C=1$}` (this is bad). -or `\tiny $C=1$` or `\small` (this is also bad).
If you want less whitespace in the node, you can use `inner sep=1pt` for the node. `text width=0.5cm` `align=center` is for if you do want line break. `\path (e) edge[-latex] (w);` is telling TikZ to crate a path, but not drawing anything and then make an extra edge(that is drawn). To make an arrow point the other way, can also switch the start and end point.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=1cm and 1cm,
  mynode/.style={draw,circle, minimum width=1.5cm},
]
\node[mynode] (z) {$Y$};
\node[mynode,right=of z] (x) {$\hat{Y}$};
\node[mynode,below=of z] (y) {$A$};
\node[mynode,below=of x] (w) {$C=1$};
\node[mynode,right=of w, fill={rgb:black,1;white,2}] (e) {$U_C$};
\draw[-latex] (z) -- (x);
\draw[-latex] (y) -- (z);
\draw[-latex] (w) -- (x);
\draw[-latex] (e) -- (w);
\draw[-latex] (y) -- (w);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Five circular nodes with arrows]

Edit: As written in the comment, you can also make this node small or tiny with an option:

```
\node[mynode,below=of x, font=\small] (w) {$C=1$};
```

Comment: How could I put the arrow from Y to \hat{Y} crossed out? If you can't simulate something like crossing out the arrow, how could I colour it red?

Thank you!

Comment: You miss the native option of Tikz `font=\small` by example.

Comment: You can use the option `[red]` or look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96967/how-can-i-strike-out-arrows-in-tikz or simply draw a small line: `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);`